# how can i get the month based on the current month in oledb command?

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I'm having a problem right now, I need to finish the system i'm currently working for my on the job training as a student. I want to get the month on my excel based on the current month using oledbdatareader and put it on a label

example:

I have 8/18/2018 up to 12/18/2018, i need to get the records from 10/18/2018.

here is my code

```
            string path = Server.MapPath("login.xlsx");
            String conString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=True;HDR=Yes;\"";

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {

                OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select [Sheet2$].[EMPLOYEE_NO],[Sheet2$].[EMPLOYEE_NAME],[Sheet2$].[HIRED_DATE],[Sheet2$].[REGULIZED_DATE],[Sheet2$].[POSITION]," +
                    "[Sheet3$].[EMPLOYEE_NO],[Sheet3$].[DATE],[Sheet3$].[REM_BALANCE]," +
                    "[Sheet4$].[EMPLOYEE_NO],[Sheet4$].[DATE],[Sheet4$].[REM_BALANCE]" +
                    " from ([Sheet2$] INNER JOIN [Sheet3$] ON [Sheet2$].[EMPLOYEE_NO]=[Sheet3$].[EMPLOYEE_NO] )" +
                    "INNER JOIN [Sheet4$] ON [Sheet3$].[EMPLOYEE_NO]=[Sheet4$].[EMPLOYEE_NO] where [Sheet2$].[EMPLOYEE_NO]=" + session + "", con);

                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();

                while (read.Read())
                {
                    Label8.Text = read["EMPLOYEE_NAME"].ToString();
                    Label9.Text = read["POSITION"].ToString();
                    Label10.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", read["HIRED_DATE"]);
                    Label11.Text = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", read["REGULIZED_DATE"]);
                    Label12.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(read["Sheet3$.DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Label13.Text = read["Sheet3$.REM_BALANCE"].ToString();
                }
```

Comment: Be careful with how your session variable is inserted into that sql statement. Your code is now open to SQL Injection attacks. Consider using CommandParameters instead.

Comment: i'm still reading about sql injection, but right now i just need to help for the command, i tried CommandParameters but it still shows the first month which is 01/18/2018, its like i need something in WHERE statement like [Sheet3$].[DATE] = *current month* NOW()

Comment: Why wouldn't you give some sample data and the desired output? You are doing a select combining 3 tables where employee_no = someValue. Considering employee_no is primary key, that may produce 1 or N rows (depends on what your data looks like really-naming sheets as sheet2,sheet3, sheet4 ... wouldn't help in guessing what they contain). If it is returning N rows (as expected), what could be the purpose of setting label values on form in a loop. Effectively you set them to the last row's values.

Comment: i just need to get the current month so that the [sheet3$].[rem_balance] will show the remaining balance for the vacation leave, i trade order by [Sheet3$].[DATE] = MONTH(NOW()) but it only show the record from 05/18/2018 *May 18, 2018*, i need to get the [sheet3$].[rem_balance] of August which is the current month right now. any help?

Comment: i change the value of Aug-18 to Aug-27 *which is the current date*in my excel and it shows when I use com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); my problem here is i want to get 18 instead of 27 but still it based on the current month, any help?